# Second function onclick not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and jquery and need your help out. I have tried searching the forums but I was unable to find a solution

i am trying to post something to a php file and then redirect to a page of my choice. The post is happening properly but not the redirect.

The html form is

```
<form action="userinfo.php" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" required maxlength=7 name="login" id="login" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
    <p><input type="password" required name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
      <label>   
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me on this computer
      </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="button" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm();redirect()" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
```

and the jquery code is

```
<script>
        function SubmitForm() {
        var login = $("#login").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        $.post("userinfo.php", {login: login, password: password },
        function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
        }
        function redirect(){
            alert("Redirecting..");
            window.location = "mainpage.html"
        }
    </script>
```

SO redirect() is obviously not being called.Any help as to why this is happening is appreciated. Please note that i am not a javascript or jquery expert. Just trying my luck to learn something.. :-)

p.s: I can redirect from the php file but wouldn't prefer to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to redirect only after the form submission(login) is successfully completed

```
<input type="button" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm()" value="Login">
```

then

```
<script>
    function SubmitForm() {
    var login = $("#login").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    $.post("userinfo.php", {login: login, password: password },
    function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        redirect();//redirect here
    });
    }
    function redirect(){
        alert("Redirecting..");
        window.location = "mainpage.html"
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function when the post request got succeeded

```
    <script>
                function SubmitForm() {
                var login = $("#login").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();

                $.post("userinfo.php", {login: login, password: password },
                function(data) {
                    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                    // calling the redirect
                    redirect();
                });
                }
                function redirect(){
                    alert("Redirecting..");
                    window.location = "mainpage.html"
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you using both form action and jquery post for same operation. Thats not a good practice.

Use jquery post data to call php and if the response id success the redirect to next page.

```
 <script>
    var login = $("#login").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    $.post("userinfo.php", {login: login, password: password },
    function(data) {
        if(data = "success"){
         console.log("Redirecting..");
         window.location = "mainpage.html"
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```